# React: Unsure why I can't run Array.map() on this array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am requesting fake company information from an API on the backend that returns an Object of a company name, company description and nested inside in an Array of jobs.

I am trying to map through the array of jobs to display them on page. But when I do, I run into an Error that says, "TypeError: jobs.map is not a function".

I bet its a simple solution, but I have been going at this for too long and its a problem I have ran into more than once, so it would be nice to understand why this happens.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import JobCard from "../components/JobCard";
import JoblyApi from '../api';

export default function CompanyDetails(){
    const [company, setCompany] = useState([]);
    const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
    const {handle} = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchCompanyDetails() {
            const res = await JoblyApi.getCompany(handle);
            setCompany(res);
            setJobs(res.jobs);
        }
        fetchCompanyDetails();
    }, []);

    return(
        <>
            <h1>{company.name}</h1>
            <p>{company.description}</p>
            {jobs.map((job) => <JobCard key={job.id} jobs={job} isTitleHidden={true} />)}
        </>
    )

}
```

[Here is a screenshot of the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNwQ1.png)

I've tested my helper functions that call the API and they work correctly. I also did a few console.log() to be sure that I was getting the array of jobs that I am expecting and I am.

[results of Array.isArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH4S3.png)

Comment: If you do `console.log(typeof res.jobs)` what do you see?

Comment: It says its an Object. I appreciate the response. But I don't quite understand why its an object when it should be an array. What is wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Arrays are objects, so typeof on an array will show "object". What does `console.log(Array.isArray(res.jobs))` show?

Comment: Can you post the response which you got after API call?

Comment: It appears your error is coming from `JobCard`, not `CompanyDetails`. You're passing a prop to `JobCard` called `jobs` and are setting it to `job`, which I doubt is an array. Check that you're not doing `jobs.map()` somewhere in your `JobCard` component

Comment: I posted a screen shot of the response in my original post. Ill also share my code from JobCard

Comment: Your right, i am calling jobs.map in my JobCard component

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I fixed it, I didnt even think of the JobCard Component

Comment: Yeah, that would be the issue then, as you're trying to call `.map()` on an individual object inside of the `res.jobs` array you shared in your screenshot

Comment: Can you log the `res.job` property? I think its type might not be an array

Answer (score -1):

Make sure jobs array is not empty. Higher other array methods are applicable on non-empty arrays only

```
{jobs.length > 0 && jobs.map((job) => <JobCard key={job.id} jobs={job} isTitleHidden={true} />)}
```

Comment: "higher order" array methods work on empty arrays also, so what you're saying in your answer isn't right. The problem is with the `JobCard` component (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75974792/react-unsure-why-i-cant-run-array-map-on-this-array?noredirect=1#comment133999593_75974792))